# Error when running script with Spyder and Python(x,y)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder, pythonxy

I've just recently installed Python(x,y) 2.7.5.1 on my computer with no other Python distributions installed in parallel and I have a problem with the Spyder IDE.

Namely when I create a script even a simple:

```
print "Hello World"
```

and I try to run it via the usual Runfile/F5 I get the following error:

```
name 'runfile' is not defined
```

As the button seems to be trying to use a `runfile()` function to run the scripts I create in the IDE.

If I try to run the same scripts by hand in Spyder's console with `execfile()` it works.

My question is how do I get the standard Run button and implicitly `runfile()` to work or alternatively to redirect the Run button to use `execfile()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to go away if from the run configuration I choose the option that each script be executed in it's own new individual console.

Comment: This also solved my problem for running PythonXY(v2.7.10.0)/Spyder scripts on WinXP, when running the Script in the Current interpreter would just hang after `runfile()`, requiring me to Force-End the python.exe process.